# Фундаментальная литература по технологиям .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Знаю, что задаю часто-повторяющийся вопрос, но таки задам.

**Есть ли на русском языке какая-либо литература по всем .NET технологиям?**

В частности, сейчас наиболее нужная тема мне - ASP.NET Core/ASP.NET Core MVC

Нужна именно фундаментальная информация о том, что происходит и как это освоить.

Мне очень тяжело читать справку о конкретных механиках без знания фундамента, на котором построена та или иная технология.

P.S. про топик [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c) я уже в курсе.

P.S.S. Мне нужно понять именно философию(если так можно выразится) разработки приложений на .NET Core и её технологиях. Прочувствовать её(вообще звучит глупо и абстрактно, но да). Я так начинал с кьютом. Я как-то сразу уловил суть процесса разработки, суть происходящего и весьма быстро понял что к чему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: Понимаю, но мне нужно не столько знать принцип работы методов/классов, сколько понять философию(если так можно сказать) разработки на данной технологии.

Comment: Это неважно дубликат есть дубликат.

Comment: Читайте in English: 1). Smith S., Architecting Modern Web Applications with ASP.NET Core and Azure, 2017.
2). De Oliveira J., Bruchet M., Learning ASP.NET Core 2.0., 2017.
3). Freeman A., Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2., 2017.
4). Freeman A., Pro Entity Framework Core 2 for ASP.NET Core MVC., 2018.