# Посоветуйте книгу по с#

Tags: c#

облазил много топиков в поисках лучшей книги, но везде пишут просто название (и при том везде разное) и не обосновывают что и чем лучше. Подскажите пожалуйста книгу и скажите почему именно она. 
Сам довольно относительно хорошо знаю плюсы.

Comment: Сейчас вас заминусуют... Здесь такие вопросы закрывают, т.к. такие вопросы влекут за собой холивары.

Comment: Всегда можно начать холивар, но я просил же обоснованный ответ)

Comment: Лучшей книги нет в природе. Если бы она была, то пропал бы смысл во всех остальных книгах. У каждой книги есть свои плюсы и минусы. Ссылку на рекомендуемые книги вам дали, ищите их, читайте отзывы, выбирайте.

Comment: Сам задавался подобным вопросом. Вот ссылка на мой топик, думаю, будет полезно) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052992/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-net